# java http server response

Tags: java, http, server, postman

I'm building a java server which have to handle http requests. I'm trying to handle a GET request and it works partially fine. In the specific case I want to discuss here I want to respond with a Json. This is what i'm doing:

```
    private Socket socket;
    OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();

    String json = gson.toJson(conversazione);

    String response =
            "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" + CRLF +
            "Content-Length: " + (json.getBytes().length)+ CRLF +
            "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8" + CRLF +
            "Server: Federico's Java Server" + CRLF +
            "Date: " + new Date() + CRLF + CRLF +
            json + CRLF + CRLF;

    outputStream.write(response.getBytes());
```

It works, i mean the client receive the status 200 OK but it receive a text instead of the Json. I'm doing a request with Postman and this is what it receive as response:

[image]

Comment: ...but that's what you're writing out in your response.  If you only wanted to write out JSON, only write out JSON.

Comment: @Makoto the string called json is actually a json. But I think you mean something else, so please can you explain yourself more?

Comment: What you say is correct @Makoto, so the key thing for you to look into Frid Ric is how you send response headers separate from the response body, at the moment it is all just text going out as the response

Comment: @Chris Separate in which way, what do you mean with separation? I can't even imagine this separation so I'm not able to think a solution

Comment: Also better call `.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UT8)`. Are you sure CRLF = `"\r\n"`? It looks inverted.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to sound unhelpful, I don't know how you confirm to the http protocol using a low level socket, I was just suggesting a direction for your investigations. Hopefully it is as simple as the idea shared by @Kirit otherwise you could look at the source of any open source servlet implementation to see how they do it - generally servlets or a framework a level up from that are the way to deal with http rather than low level socket, but doing things at that low level is a great learning opportunity.

Comment: I concur with @Joop the CRLF doesn't seem to be right. Also note the format produced by `Date.toString()` is not a correct format for HTTP, and in most environments including yours is not in GMT/UTC as required. See e.g. https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-core/blob/master/httpcore5/src/main/java/org/apache/hc/core5/http/protocol/HttpDateGenerator.java

Comment: @JoopEggen I was exactly as you said. The CRLF was inverted and now it works fine. If you want to do a separate answer I will mark it as solved.

Comment: @Chris thank you, I know you're trying to help, I appreciate every try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure CRLF = "\r\n"? It looks inverted.

"\n\r" might be interpreted as two lines (Unix+MacOS), hence the HTTP header ends after the first line.

Also better call .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UT8).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you have is that you are sending the HTTP Headers and the body together, they need to be separate.

A found [this article](https://ssaurel.medium.com/create-a-simple-http-web-server-in-java-3fc12b29d5fd) after a quick search which demonstrates this. From the code sample in that article (slightly adjusted to use the values in your sample):

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
BufferedOutputStream dataOut = new BufferedOutputStream(connect.getOutputStream());

String content = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
byte[] fileData = json.getBytes();
int fileLength = (int) file.length();

// send HTTP Headers
out.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
out.println("Server: Federico's Java Server");
out.println("Date: " + new Date());
out.println("Content-type: " + content);
out.println("Content-length: " + fileLength);
out.println(); // blank line between headers and content, very important !
out.flush(); // flush character output stream buffer
                    
dataOut.write(fileData, 0, fileLength);
dataOut.flush();
```

I encourage to go check that article out. My sample above was written manually and my not work as expected.

Comment: There is absolutely no requirement to send the headers separately (from the body, or from each other), although some servers do because it's more convenient and it is _allowed_. OTOH using `PrintWriter.println` is wrong; it uses the (local) platform EOL, which on Unix is only LF not CRLF, while HTTP spec requires CRLF (and always has) although many clients are tolerant and accept LF (similarly many servers tolerate it on requests).